# Javascript: How to grab an ID and a name attribute from a different ID?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to populate a textarea with a dynamic message. I can access and input the innerHTML, but I don't know how to pull the dynamic ID and paste it in there.

The code so far:

```
<textarea name="message" id="X-message" class="X-textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
<script>
document.getElementById('X-message').innerHTML = "Please send me more information about " + ["X-detailsField-address"];
</script>
```

The ID "X-detailsField-address" is dynamic and is what I want to enter by using the script. I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: Is the ID in a variable?

Comment: I suppose? It exists on the page dynamiccally like this:

    <div id="X-detailsField-address" class="X-detailsField"><span      class="X-detailsField-address-label X-detailsField-label">Address:    </span> 123 Fake Street
    </div>

Comment: If you know the ID in your script, why do you want to retrieve it from the DOM/markup again?

Comment: @rias Because the ID is being controlled by a third party, and I can't alter the part of the page that it's on. I can only retrieve it "again"

Comment: Where do you know from, how to retrieve the id? An element cannot have two or more IDs.

Comment: Need to show sample html of where ID comes from, we can't read minds. Also you are concatenating a string and an array which doesn't make sense

Answer (score -1, accepted):

demo here http://jsfiddle.net/64e3ecvh/4/

```
var addressDiv =document.querySelector('div[id*="detailsField-address"]');
console.log(addressDiv.innerText);
```

Comment: `innerText` is not very browser compatible. You might want to do `addressDiv.innerText || addressDiv.textContent`

Answer (score 0):

If there is a specific pattern for that ID, you can do something like this using jQuery (a really useful javascript library when it comes to things like this) -

```
$('textarea[id*="detailsField-address"]')
```

The following code is an example -

```js
$('textarea[id*=message]').html("Please send me more information about " + $('textarea[id*=detailsFieldaddress]').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="message" id="X-message" class="X-textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
<textarea name="message" id="X-details" class="X-textarea" rows="3">Some Details</textarea>
<textarea name="message" id="X-field" class="X-textarea" rows="3">Some fields</textarea>
<textarea name="message" id="X-detailsFieldaddress" class="X-textarea" rows="3">123 West Street</textarea>
```

The above code will obviously find the textareas based on a specific pattern, but you'll have to iterate through them to find the exact textarea you're looking for, if there many textareas having the same pattern of IDs.